# PHP Array Parsing sitemap in robots.txt

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, foreach

I am having some issues trying to get the url data from an array using php.

My code is and im trying to get each sitemap mentioned in robots.txt file

```
$robots_file = file_get_contents($robotsTXT);
$pattern = "/Sitemap: ([^\r\n]*)/";
$i = preg_match_all($pattern, $robots_file, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);

print_r($match);
```

print_r($match); returns below

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [0] => Sitemap: http://www.google.com/culturalinstitute/sitemap.xml 
    [1] => http://www.google.com/culturalinstitute/sitemap.xml ) 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => Sitemap: http://www.google.com/hostednews/sitemap_index.xml 
    [1] => http://www.google.com/hostednews/sitemap_index.xml ) 
    [2] => Array ( [0] => Sitemap: http://www.google.com/sitemaps_webmasters.xml 
    [1] => http://www.google.com/sitemaps_webmasters.xml ) 
    [3] => Array ( [0] => Sitemap: http://www.google.com/ventures/sitemap_ventures.xml 
    [1] => http://www.google.com/ventures/sitemap_ventures.xml ) 
    [4] => Array ( [0] => Sitemap: http://www.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sitemaps/sitemap_index.xml [1] => http://www.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sitemaps/sitemap_index.xml ) 
    [5] => Array ( [0] => Sitemap: http://www.gstatic.com/earth/gallery/sitemaps/sitemap.xml 
    [1] => http://www.gstatic.com/earth/gallery/sitemaps/sitemap.xml ) 
    [6] => Array ( [0] => Sitemap: http://www.gstatic.com/s2/sitemaps/profiles-sitemap.xml 
    [1] => http://www.gstatic.com/s2/sitemaps/profiles-sitemap.xml ) 
    [7] => Array ( [0] => Sitemap: http://www.gstatic.com/trends/websites/sitemaps/sitemapindex.xml 
    [1] => http://www.gstatic.com/trends/websites/sitemaps/sitemapindex.xml )
)
```

What i want to do is display the address like so

```
http://www.google.com/culturalinstitute/sitemap.xml
http://www.google.com/hostednews/sitemap_index.xml
http://www.google.com/sitemaps_webmasters.xml 
http://www.google.com/ventures/sitemap_ventures.xml
http://www.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sitemaps/sitemap_index.xml
http://www.gstatic.com/earth/gallery/sitemaps/sitemap.xml 
http://www.gstatic.com/s2/sitemaps/profiles-sitemap.xml
http://www.gstatic.com/trends/websites/sitemaps/sitemapindex.xml
```

i tried writing a for each loop but i could not get it to work.

```
foreach( $match as $sitemap){

echo $sitemap[1];

}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$robots_file = file_get_contents($robotsTXT);

$pattern = '/Sitemap: ([^\s]+)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $robots_file, $match);

print_r($match[1]);

foreach ($match[1] as $sitemap)
{
    echo $sitemap . "<br />\n";
}
```

You dont need to loop through entire matched array, just need to loop through the array which is $match[1].

Comment: This just returns Sitemap: http://www.google.com/hostednews/sitemap_index.xmlhttp://www.google.com/hostednews/sitemap_index.xml

Comment: Did you use the code verbatim? I tested and the entirety of my code and it returns the urls for each sitemap.

Comment: I added a newline and <br /> as well so it will output it on a new line in case you wanted it that way.

Comment: Hi i used the following to get it to work foreach($match as $sitemap){ echo $sitemap[1]. "</br/>";}

Comment: see my comment for above answer, it's inefficient and incorrect way to do it.

Comment: Try my code exactly as I have it in its entirety and you will get the correct result, and it correctly goes about doing it.

Comment: Could you recommend a more efficient method?

Comment: The more efficient method is the code I have posted, use it fully.

Answer (score 2):

instead of `echo $sitemap;` try `echo $sitemap[1];`

Comment: This would be inefficient as it is still needlessly passing a multi-dimensional array to the foreach() loop when all OP has to do is pass the correct single dimension array from the match.

Comment: Do you recommend a different way of doing this?

Comment: In this situation the amount of data being processed is quite small, so I prefer easier to read code than memory use optimization.

Comment: How is adding the array index reference to $sitemap any more readable than adding it to $match? Your argument makes no sense, but whatever you say.